# Android 10 Notification image not showing. Always showing like default notification style

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-10.0

I am coding an app which has notification feature. I have implemented FCM. everything was fine but when i upgraded to android 10 the notification is showing as i want its always showing like default style having simple title and body. i tried to change a lot but each time i got the same thing.

**Even i am not setting the title and text received by fcm still its showing title and body as received by fcm**

**I have used a large icon image that also not showing**

its happening only on android 10 above works fine in Android 9. pls help here is code snippet of fcm service.

**firebasemessagingservice.java**

```
public class firebasemessagingservice 
extends FirebaseMessagingService { 
    private Bitmap getBitmapfromUrl(String string2) { 
        try { 
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(string2).openConnection(); 
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true); 
            httpURLConnection.connect(); 
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)httpURLConnection.getInputStream()); 
            return bitmap; 
        } 
        catch (Exception exception) { 
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(); 
            stringBuilder.append("Error in getting notification image: "); 
            stringBuilder.append(exception.getLocalizedMessage()); 
            Log.e((String)"awesome", (String)stringBuilder.toString()); 
            return null; 
        } 
    } 

    private void sendNotification(String string2, String string3, String string4, String string5) { 
        Intent intent = new Intent((Context)this, dashboard.class); 
        intent.addFlags(67108864); 
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity((Context)this, (int)0, (Intent)intent, (int)1073741824); 
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)this.getSystemService("notification"); 
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) { 
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(new NotificationChannel("General", (CharSequence)"General", 4)); 
        } 
        Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri((int)2); 
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder((Context)this, "General").setSmallIcon(2131165441).setContentTitle((CharSequence)string5).setContentText((CharSequence)string5).setAutoCancel(true).setSound(uri).setContentIntent(pendingIntent).setStyle((NotificationCompat.Style)new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText((CharSequence)string3)); 
        if (string4 != null) { 
            builder.setLargeIcon(this.getBitmapfromUrl(string4)); 
        } 
        notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build()); 
    } 

    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) { 
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) { 
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(); 
            stringBuilder.append("Message data payload: "); 
            stringBuilder.append((Object)remoteMessage.getData()); 
            Log.d((String)"Constraints", (String)stringBuilder.toString()); 
        } 
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) { 
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(); 
            stringBuilder.append("Message Notification Body: "); 
            stringBuilder.append(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()); 
            Log.d((String)"Constraints", (String)stringBuilder.toString()); 
        } 
        String string2 = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(); 
        String string3 = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(); 
        String string4 = (String)remoteMessage.getData().get((Object)"icon"); 
        String string5 = (String)remoteMessage.getData().get((Object)"body1"); 
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(); 
        stringBuilder.append(" icon "); 
        stringBuilder.append(string4); 
        Log.d((String)"Constraints", (String)stringBuilder.toString()); 
        this.sendNotification(string2, string3, string4, string5); 
    } 

    public void onNewToken(String string2) { 
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(); 
        stringBuilder.append("Refreshed token: "); 
        stringBuilder.append(string2); 
        Log.d((String)"Constraints", (String)stringBuilder.toString()); 
    }
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Not yet bro....

Answer (score 0):

The same problem occurring for me in Android 10. Then I used the Glide library to generate the bitmap. If the bitmap loads then I send notification with image.

```
Glide.with(this)
    .asBitmap()
    .load(**imageURL**)
    .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
            if(resource!=null){
                    //your notification code
             }

        @Override
        public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {
        }
    });
```